# Dropdown menu not being displayed on first click after being created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dropdown menu which is being populated dynamically when the button is pressed however the content is not being displayed until the button is clicked several times, once it has been displayed it works ok.
The HTML is:

```js
$('#btnGroupDrop1').on( 'click', $('#availableVans'), function() {
           getAvailableVans();
          });

    function getAvailableVans() {
         $.ajax({
          url: "${ctx}/str/getDeliveryVans.jx?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}",
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: function(data) {
             var buttonHtml = '<button id="buttonGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Add new list for:</button>\n';
             var divHeader  = '<div id="availableVans" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="buttonGroupDrop1">\n';
    
             var vanList    = "";
           $.each( data.vans ,function( idx, van ){
            var userVan = '<a class="dropdown-item newListBtn" data-id="' + van.id + '" data-color="' + van.strelColor + '" data-user="' + van.username + '">' + van.username + '</a>';
            vanList = vanList + userVan + "\n";
           });
           var allVans = '<a class="dropdown-item newListBtn" data-id="0" data-color="" data-user="ALL VANS">ALL VANS</a>\n';
    
             var divFooter = '</div>';
    
           $('#buttonGroup').html( buttonHtml + divHeader +  vanList + allVans + divFooter);
    
          },
          error: function(data,status,er) {
           alert("Failure to retrieve list of vans");
          }
         });
    
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonGroup" class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
             Add new list for:
           </button>
           <div id="availableVans" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
            <c:forEach var="van" items="${map.vans}" varStatus="status">
               <a class="dropdown-item newListBtn" data-id="${van.id}" data-color="${van.strelColor}" data-user="${van.username}">${van.username}</a>
         </c:forEach>
         <a class="dropdown-item newListBtn" data-id="0" data-color="" data-user="">ALL VANS</a>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: if this click $('#btnGroupDrop1').on( 'click', $('#availableVans'), function() {
                      getAvailableVans();
                  });
is for button then try following
$('#btnGroupDrop1').on( 'click',  function() {
                      getAvailableVans();
                  });

Comment: Why do you appended
  var buttonHtml = '<button id="buttonGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Add new list for:</button>\n';
 line again?

Answer (score 0):

after the click should be a selector and you wrote an element
change this code

```
$('#btnGroupDrop1').on( 'click', $('#availableVans'), function() {
     getAvailableVans();
});
```

to

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#btnGroupDrop1', function() {
     getAvailableVans();
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me so quickly, I have made the change you suggest but the issue is still the same:

Comment: You are calling the ajax on click, when you click the dropdown you call it again but you have the list from the previews click. you should call the ajax when the page is loading then the dropdown would open in 1 click